# Tabhost, how to get to constructor ? (ANDROID)

Tags: android, android-activity, android-tabhost

Whan I have got a tabhost and impolement the tabs. How I can get to tab constructor to pass some variables?

```
    TabSpec architectureSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("architecture");
    architectureSpec.setIndicator(architecture);
    Intent architectureIntent = new Intent(this, ArchitectureTab.class);
    architectureSpec.setContent(architectureIntent);
```

And I would like get to ArchitectureTab before or right after "onCreate" method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass variables to the `ArchitectureTab` class via `Intent.putExtra()` and read them from this activity via `getIntent().getExtra()`